# Foxypreviewer report Pdf dimension setting for chained reports to single pdf

Tags: pdf, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am facing strange with the PDF printing with Foxypreviewer in Visual foxpro while trying to print multiple reports to one pdf using "NOPAGEEJECT".
We have some reports, which are supposed to be printed on in the vertical direction while other reports are supposed to be printed in the horizontal direction.
Now I get all pages in the same direction, depending on which direction the first report in the template have.Sample code is given below which I am trying to print to pdf:

```
REPORT FORM Itinerary01 object type 10 NOCONSOLE NOPAGEEJECT
REPORT FORM Itinerary02 object type 10 NOCONSOLE
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Since my answer was deleted, hopefully I can get this info to you here in a comment. 

I came up against this issue some time back. I have an in-depth post about the technique I used (with a lot of help from Lisa Slater Nicholls at spacefold.com) to combine portrait and landscape reports into one PDF. Hope it helps.

https://sjwiley.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/combining-portrait-and-landscape-reports-into-one-print-job-in-vfp9/

(My post indicates you can download the source I used, but the link appears to be dead. I'll add a comment if/when I'm able to locate it.)

Comment: I updated the link in my post so you can download the example source. Here it is as well: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsZ6BA3G2lpLqjDdTht-Dckn26KZ

Comment: Hi Steve,I am sorry.I think this solution will not work with Foxypreviewer .

Answer (score 0):

The magic is that if I run these file one by one then only the last one will go for pdf but when I selected both and execute, the result was OK.

You are running files from command prompt so you can not get desired result. Put these command in a prg and see the magic.

```
REPORT FORM LOCFILE(_Samples + "\Solution\Reports\Colors.frx") ;
    OBJECT TYPE 10 NOPAGEEJECT NORESET TO FILE "d:\Test.pdf"
REPORT FORM LOCFILE(_Samples + "\Solution\Reports\Percent.frx") ;
    OBJECT TYPE 10 PREVIEW
```